# Arredondamento em C

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia ignorar arredondamentos em divisões, por exemplo:

> 4/3 = 1,33... ~ 1 | 5/3 = 1,66... ~ 2

Certo?

Eu queria fazer um programa em C, que nesses casos, o arredondamento não seja feito, pois a ideia é incrementar um número caso ele contenha decimais, independentemente se o número decimal (número duvidoso) for maior, menor ou igual a 5. Alguma ideia?

Código:

```c
void main() {

  float n1 = 4.0;
  float n2 = 3.0;

  float result;

  result = n1 / n2; // res = 1,33 ~ 1

  // Aqui eu quero que o resultado seja 2
  printf("Resultado incrementado: %d\n", result);

  n1 = 5;
  result = n1 / n2; // res = 1,66 ~ 2

  // Aqui eu quero que o resultado seja 2
  printf("Resultado incrementado: %d\n", result);

}
```

No primeiro `printf` é preciso eu incrementar para obter o resultado desejado, no segundo não. Ou seja, ele usa as regras do arredondamento. O que eu quero, é que se há decimais no número, que ele seja incrementado e não decrementado.

Comment: Mostre o que você já fez para entendermos o que está errado.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo

Comment: voce sabe que já que seu "result" é uma variável do tipo "int", ele nunca vai coner as partes decimais, não?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A biblioteca (math.h) até 2010 não implementava a função `round()` por natureza, existiam somente duas funções que faziam isso por meio de conceitos matemáticos.

**floor()**

Implementa o conceito de chão. Resumidamente é o primeiro inteiro encontrado menor do que o valor resultado da operação

Exemplos:

- `floor(1.3) // retorna 1`
- `floor(2.9) // retorna 2`

**ceil()**

Implementa o conceito de teto. Resumidamente é o primeiro inteiro encontrado maior do que o valor resultado da operação

Exemplos:

- `ceil(1.1)  // retorna 2`
- `ceil(3.6)  // retorna 4`

Em 2011 foi implementada a função `round()` à biblioteca `math.h`.

**round()**

Retorna o inteiro mais próximo do número passado como argumento.

Exemplos:

- `round(1.4) //retorna 1`
- `round(3.6) //retorna 4`

É possível fazer a sua própria implementação para a função `round()` caso não se deseje incluir a biblioteca ao seu projeto.

**Implementação**

Eu geralmente adiciono essa função, evitando uma biblioteca extra:

```
int round(double number)
{
    return (number >= 0) ? (int)(number + 0.5) : (int)(number - 0.5);
}
```

Onde é somado/subtraído 0.5 ao número, e o mesmo truncado para inteiro, resultando em uma implementação perfeita de `round()`

fonte: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58289/C-Round-Function

Comment: Acrescentando um pouco de teoria: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parte_inteira

Comment: Obrigado, a função ceil(double *) resolveu o meu problema!!!